# Node.js 16 on AWS ELB having random 502s from nginx

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb, http-status-code-502

My application is running on the latest Node.js LTS version on AWS ELB and when I am running some performance scripts I get random 502's from nginx.

Currently I have the following settings regarging timeout:

```
server.timeout = 600 * 1000;
server.keepAliveTimeout = 630 * 1000;
server.headersTimeout = 660 * 1000;
```

On AWS the connection idle timeout is set to 60 seconds.

Comment: Have you investigated any logs or metrics? Is your process failing or timing out health checks under high load? Are you getting high event loop lag? Analyzing the results of a performance test is a complex topic and there isn't much information here.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?